# Assembly x86-64 setting carry flag for sub instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64, carryflag

I am working through [Richard Detmer's Assembly Language book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/128403612X).

The first chapter states:

`A borrow occurs in the subtraction a - b when b is larger than a as unsigned numbers. Computer hardware can detect a borrow in subtraction by looking at whether a carry occurred in the corresponding addition. If there is no carry in the addition, then there is a borrow in the subtraction. If there is a carry in the addition, then there is no borrow in the subtraction.`

The carry flag is the 0th bit of the `EFL` register.

Suppose we want to perform 195D - 618D = -423D as a subtraction operation. There is a borrow and hence the carry flag should not be set.

The following asm code compiles and runs, yet after `sub rax, 618`, the carry flag is indeed set.

The corresponding addition would be 00C3h + FD96h and this does not involve a carry since the final pairwise addition is 0 + F with no carry into it and hence, there is no carry out of the final pairwise addition.

```
 .DATA
number  QWORD   195
sum     QWORD   ?

.CODE
main    PROC
        mov     rax, number     ; 195 to RAX
        sub     rax, 618        ; subtract 618
             ;at this point, however, the carry flag is indeed set to 1. Why is this?
        mov     sum, rax        ; sum to memory

        mov     rax, 0          ; return code
        ret                     ; exit to operating system

main    ENDP

END
```

I am unclear about how this could be.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is just a simple misunderstanding, a borrow for a SUB *does* get signaled by the carry flag.  There is no dedicated "borrow" flag, the carry flag can do both jobs.  There is no ambiguity since you know whether you just did an ADD or a SUB.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, It is my oversight. Later in the text, it does indeed talk about the effect of add and sub on the flags and what you have mentioned is indeed clarified.

Comment: Fun fact: in some non-x86 architectures (like ARM), the carry flag is still a carry, not a borrow for subtraction.  So it's basically inverted from the way x86 uses it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag#Carry_flag_vs._borrow_flag.  That's why ARM has an `sbc` instruction (sub with carry) instead of x86's `sbb` (sub with borrow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First understand that there is unsigned integer arithmetic (where overflow is indicated by the carry flag) and signed integer arithmetic (where overflow is indicated by the overflow flag).

The same addition and subtraction instructions are used for both unsigned and signed integer arithmetic. The only difference is which flags you test afterwards and how you interpret the result (e.g. as -0x0000423D or as 0xFFFFBDC3).

A borrow is also indicated by the carry flag. This means that a borrow happens whenever an unsigned integer overflow happened. For `0x0000195D - 0x0000618D` there is an unsigned integer overflow (unsigned integers can't be negative), so the carry flag will be set (but there wasn't a signed integer overflow, so the overflow flag won't be set). The result will be 0xFFFFBDC3 or -0x0000423D depending on whether the result was supposed to be signed or unsigned.